# ArcGIS Online - Unable to upload a shapefile with over 250,000 points as hosted feature service

Tags: arcgis-online

I have a shapefile with over 250,000 points.

I've tried to upload it as a hosted feature service but it does not populate the attribute table.

It seems to time out despite the option to "keep me always signed in" has been selected.

Anybody know how to upload the file so I can use it in a web map?

Comment: what is the size of your zipped shapefile? Can you publish this shapefile through ArcMap or Pro?

Comment: I don't think you can store that many. See this http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/42465

Comment: the feature limit upload is only for feature collections like shp & csvs that have not been published to feature services.